# ffmpeg recipe for mxf file

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Can someone help me develop a command for producing a file that has these specs:

```
MXF (OP-1a) 

# Audio Channels
>= 8

Resolution
1280x720    

Drop Frame
Yes

Bit Rate
>= 50 Mbps  

Frame Rate
59.940 fps
```

Comment: `man ffmpeg` is definitely worth a look.

Comment: What did you try already? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: We ended up using Apple Compressor to solve this, thanks.